# python regex: extract string from escaped sequences

Tags: python, regex

I do not get it. Why people down vote this without explanation? What mistake I made?

How to extract `Apple Recipe`, `3`, `pages`, `29.4KB` from the following string?

```
'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tApple Recipe\r\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tpages\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t29.4KB\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t'
```

I've tried `re.compile('\w+')` but can only get results like:

`Apple`

`Recipe`

`29`

`.`

`4`

`KB`

However, I want to get them together as they are, not separately. For example, I want to get `Apple Recipe` together but not as two separate tokens.

Comment: You can just join the result with a comma, did you try this?

Comment: @EdChum In that case `Apple Recipe` would be `Apple, Recipe`:P That's not what I want

Comment: If you want to group your result delimited on whitespace except space, use `[\w ]+`. (There is a space after the \w.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = """\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tApple Recipe\r\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tpages\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t29.4KB\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t"""

import re

g = re.findall(r'[^\r\n\t]+', data)
print(g)
```

Prints:

```
['Apple Recipe', '3', 'pages', '29.4KB']
```

The `[^\r\n\t]+` will match any string that doesn't contain `\r`, `\n` or `\t` characters.

Comment: I was going to answer with `re.split('[\t\r\n]+', g)` which gives roughly the same results.

Comment: Many thanks! I also found `[\S ]` useful in this case:D

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = """\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tApple Recipe\r\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tpages\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t29.4KB\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t"""

import re

output = re.findall(r'\w+[.\d]?\w+', txt)
print(output)
```

u will get the required output

```
['Apple', 'Recipe', '3', 'pages', '29.4KB']
```